# "Invalid Form Data" in file upload on slack API

Tags: swift, swiftui, slack, slack-api

I'm working on a project where I need to upload files to channels in a slack workspace using slack's API. This is how I'm reading the file contents:

```swift
func readFile(localFilePath: String) -> Data? {
        var contents: Data
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: localFilePath)
        
        do {
            contents = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }

        return contents
    }
```

However, this is what I get on slack:

[image]

I have also tried reading the file as a `String`, like this:

```swift
contents = try String(contentsOf: url, encoding: .ascii)
```

This way slack appears to recognize it's a PDF, but it's blank (see image below).

[image]

If I add an explicit `Content-Type` header and set it to `multipart/form-data;`, I get an `invalid_form_data` error in response.

Here's the request code:

```swift
let reqHeaders: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Authorization": "",
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data;",
        ]
let params: [String:Any] = [
            "channels": channelSelections.joined(separator: ","),
            "content": fileData,
            "initial_comment": messageText,
            "filename": filename
        ]
        AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, headers: reqHeaders).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let data = response.data {
                    do {
                        let json = try JSON(data: data)
                        if json["ok"].boolValue {
                            // some code
                        } else {
                            print("\n\n\n\(json)\n\n\n")
                        }
                    }
                    catch{
                        print("JSON Error")
                    }
                    
                }
            case let .failure(error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
```

What's the correct way to read the file and send as payload to slack's API?

Comment: can you post your multipart request

Comment: "What's the correct way to achieve this?"  What is 'this'?  First, you say you are trying to upload files to some guys, which you call 'channels.'  You then say you are trying to read the content of a file.  What is your objective?  What are channels?  Where do your files come from?

Comment: This is not a multipart, but a regular Post request. Instead you should do a multipart